# How to show a desktop site in a web interface Android app?

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm fairly new to android apps and would like some help on how to show a desktop site, rather than the standard mobile site in my app I will leave my source code so far below.

Thank you so much for your time and any help is appreciated:

```
package com.example.matthayllar.whatsappweb;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;
/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
 * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
 */
private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
private View mContentView;
private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

        // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
        // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
        // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
};
private View mControlsView;
private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed display of UI elements
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.show();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
private boolean mVisible;
private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hide();
    }
};
/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Add content to app
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}

private void toggle() {
    if (mVisible) {
        hide();
    } else {
        show();
    }
}

private void hide() {
    // Hide UI first
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVisible = false;

    // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void show() {
    // Show the system bar
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    mVisible = true;

    // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question comes up short on quite a few things. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this library: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView.

There is also an example(for Activity or Fragment):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

private AdvancedWebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setListener(this, this);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.org/");

    // ...
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
    // ...
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mWebView.onPause();
    // ...
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mWebView.onDestroy();
    // ...
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mWebView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
    // ...
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) { }

@Override
public void onPageFinished(String url) { }

@Override
public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) { }

@Override
public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) { }

@Override
public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) { }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, it is a great help and will enjoy learning how to do this.

Can't believe two people gave me a bad score and weren't helpful when i'm a student trying to expand my knowledge lol